# jquery Click Simulation using class attribute not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to simulate click on a button from [visjs](http://visjs.org) library in my angular app.
The class of that button, in the library is `.vis-zoomExtends`.
I've tried the following 2 ways, but neither of these is working:

```
        angular.element('.vis-zoomExtends').trigger('click');
```

and

```
        angular.element('.vis-zoomExtends')[0].click();
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here ?

**EDIT:** This is the click button on which I'm trying to simulate click event:
[Vis navigation buttons](http://visjs.org/examples/network/other/navigation.html)

Comment: i think it is triggering but there seems to be no click handler for that button thats thye reason you are not able to see anything happening. thats what i saw in the developer tools. There is no click handler for the element in the link you have provided.

Comment: You mean the line which says 'user-select: none;'  ?

Comment: in the EventListeners tab there is no handler for click event

Comment: if you can create a working demo of this. I may be able to help better and help you solve the issue. create a Plnkr or fiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use standard DOM API, [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) does not find elements by tag name / CSS selector.

```
document.querySelector('.vis-zoomExtends').click();
```

Comment: @SaurabhVerma, first check are you able to get the element

Comment: Yes, using breakpoint, I can see that I'm getting the correct div element. However, the expected click event is not getting triggered

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelector` inside element.

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('.vis-zoomExtends')).click();
```

Or use `triggerHandler`.

```
 angular.element('.vis-zoomExtends').triggerHandler('click');
```

Comment: This is also not simulating the click event.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about angular js  what it does or can do. but you can use jquery's trigger function totrigger a click event

```
$('#parent_element').find('your_elemnt').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Yes, I've also read that. However, in my case, this element is a part of a library, which has only a specific class, and not an id. And when I'm trying to perform this on a class, then it's not simulating the click

Comment: $('.class_name')...... is used in case of class. I think you are not able to do this because the element your are refering to is either created by the js library  or class is given by the library at the client side, it doesn't come from server. like most plugins do , that you just give the plugin id of the element and plugin creates rest of the html for you. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the element here is actually created by the js library

Comment: can you provide me the link and other info where this is being implemented(if possible),

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135926/discussion-between-prabhjot-and-saurabh-verma).